# How to store large sequences of doubles as literal string in javascript file

Tags: javascript, base64, decode

What is the best way to store ca. 100 sequences of doubles directly in the js file? Each sequence will have length of ca. 10 000 doubles or more.

Requirements

- the javascript file must be executed as fast as possible
- it is enough for me to iterate through the sequence on demand (I do not need to decode all the numbers at js execution. They will be decoded on event.)
- it shouldn't take to much space

The simplest option is probably to use string of CSV format but then the doubles are not stored in the most efficient manner, right?

Another option might be to store the numbers in Base64 byte array, but then I have no idea how to read the base64 string into double.

EDIT:

I would like to use the doubles to transform Matrix4x4 of 3d nodes in Adobe 3D annotations. Adobe allows to import external files but it is so complicated that it might be simpler to include all the data in the js file directly.

Comment: What are you using these doubles for? Perhaps if we can see the big picture, there may be a more efficient solution than what you mentioned.

Comment: I would like to use the doubles to transform Matrix4x4 of 3d nodes in Adobe 3D annotations. Adobe allows to import external files but it is so complicated that it might be simpler to include all the data in the js file directly.

Comment: How are you generating these numbers? Unless you actually have time to enter a million numbers, you must be using something to generate them, suggesting that there may be a formula to calculate them, rather than actually including them.

Comment: I generate them by a very very time consuming simulation

Comment: I see. Do you have a problem with using literal values? According to my calculations (using the numbers you have given), direct encoding yields a data size of 8MB, base64 encoding yields a size of 10.7MB, and using literal values yields a size from 2MB to 16MB.

Comment: Not at all. You are probably right that it is the most efficient way of storing values when taking into account the implementation time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, it is probably not worth it to try and encode the values. Here are some values from my head on the required amount of data to store doubles (updated from comment).

Assuming 1,000,000 values:

- Using direct encoding (won't work well in a JS file): 8 B = 8 MB
- Using base64: 10.7 B = 10.7 MB
- Literals (best case): 1 B + delimiter = 2 MB
- Literals (worst case): 21 B + delimiter = 22 MB
- Literals (average case assuming evenly distributed values): 19 B + delimiter = 20MB

Note: A double can take 21 bytes (assuming 15 digits of precision) in the worst case like this: 1.23456789101112e-131

As you can see, you still won't be able to cut it below 1/2 of using plain literal values with encoding, and if you plan on doing random-access decoding it will get complicated fast. It may be best to stick to literals. You might get some benefit from using the external file that you mentioned, but that depends on how much effort is needed to do so.

Some ideas on how to optimize using literals:

- Depending on the precision required, you could approximate the values and limit a value to, say, 5 digits of precision. This would incredibly shorten the file.
- You could compress the file. I think you can specify any number of doubles using 14 characters, (`0123456789.e-,`) so theoretically, you could compress such a string to half its size. I don't know how good practical modern compression routines are though.